# My lambda expression isn't producing the result I expected

Tags: c#, lambda

```
courses = courses.Where(
                c => queryParameters.ShowInActive || c.Flags.Contains((ulong)CourseFlags.Active) 
                     &&
                     (queryParameters.AuthorId <= 0 ||
                      (c.Authors != null && c.Authors.Exists(a => a.ID == queryParameters.AuthorId)))
                     &&
                     (queryParameters.CategoryIDs == null || queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Count == 0 ||
                      (c.Tags != null && c.Tags.Any(t => queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Contains(t.ID)))
                      &&
                      queryParameters.CourseIDs == null || queryParameters.CourseIDs.Count == 0 ||
                      queryParameters.CourseIDs.Contains(c.ID))
                ).ToList();
```

The issue is that `queryParameters.CourseIDS.Count()` returns 157 but the lambda expression above returns 2500 records. What am I doing wrong?

I've also made sure that `ShowInactive` is set to true and `CategoryIDs` is null and `AuthorId` is 0

Comment: How many objects/records are in `courses`? Other than having an `Id`, a list of `Tags` and a list of `Authors` what can you tell us about the data in `courses`?

Comment: Just rewrite this without a lambda expression. It's not readable. The main reason you use a lambda expression is to reduce clutter by not having to declare delegates that have trivial implementations (like a 1 liner that takes 5 lines to declare and use).

Comment: A note about the title... your lambda is working as written. Maybe 'My lambda expression isn't producing the results I expect' is a better title.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive input. I've changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is around operator precedence, specifically && has a higher precedence than ||. So without spending too much on this, try the following:

```
courses = courses.Where(
            c => (queryParameters.ShowInActive || c.Flags.Contains((ulong)CourseFlags.Active))
                 &&
                 (queryParameters.AuthorId <= 0 ||
                  (c.Authors != null && c.Authors.Exists(a => a.ID == queryParameters.AuthorId)))
                 &&
                 ((queryParameters.CategoryIDs == null || queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Count == 0 ||
                  (c.Tags != null && c.Tags.Any(t => queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Contains(t.ID))))
                  &&
                  (queryParameters.CourseIDs == null || queryParameters.CourseIDs.Count == 0 ||
                  queryParameters.CourseIDs.Contains(c.ID)))
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and voila! I also can see the operator precedence causing an issue on my end.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: You forgot some parentheses.

As written, when the `queryParamters.ShowInActive` is set to `true`, the predicate returns `true` and all your records are returned. Therefore, all records are returned. You seem to want to use all of the query parameters. Try adding some whitespace to this complicated query for clarity. Or consider splitting it into many `Where()` calls.

```
courses = courses.Where(
              c => (
                    queryParameters.ShowInActive
                    ||
                    c.Flags.Contains((ulong)CourseFlags.Active)
              ) && (
                    queryParameters.AuthorId <= 0
                    || (
                        c.Authors != null
                        &&
                        c.Authors.Exists(a => a.ID == queryParameters.AuthorId)
                       )
              ) && (
                    queryParameters.CategoryIDs == null
                    ||
                    queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Count == 0
                    || (
                        c.Tags != null
                        &&
                        c.Tags.Any(t => queryParameters.CategoryIDs.Contains(t.ID))
                       )
              ) && (
                    queryParameters.CourseIDs == null
                    ||
                    queryParameters.CourseIDs.Count == 0
                    ||
                    queryParameters.CourseIDs.Contains(c.ID)
                   )
              )
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: That's a complicated way to say: You forgot a parenthesis.

Comment: In addition, I think he wants to parenthesize the last three (i.e. `(queryParameters.CourseIDs == null || queryParameters.CourseIDs.Count == 0 ||
queryParameters.CourseIDs.Contains(c.ID))`

Comment: If this is linq to sql then it will not short circuit like linq to object will.

Comment: @TravisJ Still `x OR y AND z` is distinct from `(x OR y) AND z`, no matter if you short-circuit or not.

Comment: @Jeppe - My comment was in response to "the evaluation stops there", where the evaluation will decidedly continue in linq to sql.